# The limit implied by an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

If $1 \ge F(y) > 1 - \epsilon$ for each $\epsilon >0$, how does this prove that 
$\lim_{y\rightarrow\infty} F(y) = 1$ when F is a right-continuous non-decreasing
function.
Thanks

Comment: If $1 \geq F(y) > 1 - \varepsilon$ for each $\varepsilon > 0$, then $F(y) = 1$, so $\lim_{y\to\infty}F(y) = 1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: The variable $y$ should be quantified in your assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's non-decreasing and continuous so $f(y)<f(y+\delta y)$ given that $y<y+\delta y$. So as you progress right it gets closer and closer to the upper bound $1$ shown in the inequality.  At infinity this will finally reach the upper bound 1 because it can't get further away from the upper bound. If it were to go down at any point it wouldn't be non-decreasing.

This is also assuming $F(y) \neq constant$.

Here is an example of a function that meets that criteria on the interval  $(0,\infty]$:

$$F(y) = e^{({-1\over y})}$$